# Is there a framework which makes developing Mac apps feel more like developing iOS apps?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, macos, cocoa, appkit

Loren Brichter, the genius behind Twitter for Mac, once said that he has built a wrapper around Cocoa / App Kit so that it felt more like UIKit. Unfortunately I can't find the resource anymore where I heard that.

I'm struggling a lot trying to build a simple Mac app although have been developing iOS apps for a couple of years.

Are there wrappers or frameworks which make AppKit feel more natural to iOS developers?
Are there books for developing Mac apps, targeted at iOS app developers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TwUI was new to me, but IconFactory (who, incidentally, make Twitteriffic) have released http://chameleonproject.org/ with much the same scope.

Comment: Chameleon indeed looks more powerful than TwUI at a first glimpse!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this one is meant: https://github.com/twitter/twui

And here an article covering TwUI: http://engineering.twitter.com/2011/07/starting-today-twitter-is-offering-twui.html

> TwUI brings the philosophy of UIKit to the desktop. It is built on top of Core Animation, and it borrows interaction ideas from AppKit. It allows for all the things Mac users expect, including drag & drop, mouse events, tooltips, Mac-like text selection, and so on. And, since TwUI isn’t bound by the constraints of an existing API, developers can experiment with new features like block-based drawRect and layout.
>   [image]